# insufficient storage

Tags: insufficient-memory

ALright I have the netbook. I recently did a reset and now I cannot load any apps. It's telling me the internal memory is full and I do not know how to erase things and clear it since it won't let me even download an app to debug/clear cache/clean it. 
Who has some helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You reset your phone means there will be no apps in that.To find out what's occupying your phone memory goto settings -> manage application or settings->storage option to find out what's occupying space in your device.
Another way: If you have any file manager application installed in your phone  go to internal storage and find out the things which occupying space in your phone.It may be any files such pictures or videos.